# Best Practice to pass *gorm.db instance in a custom handler in go http

Tags: database, go, go-gorm, mux

I am creating a custom web handler to handle my routes in an web application.

The handler is

```
type CustomHandler struct{
Db *gorm.DB
}
```

Then a receiver function:

```
func (h CustomHandler) Index() http.Handler {
   return http.handlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
   //Some code
   //use h.Db.Find() ,etc.
})
```

I am passing this to my router as

```
//In package 
customHandler := &CustomHandler{*gormInstance} //I've already got the instance
router.Handle("/someroute", customHandler.index() )
```

But a problem with this is gorm.DB instance, being a pointer will mutate once it pass through a route during one request.
Do I have to generate different copies of the initial gorm instance? If so, How can I pass them through each routes on each requests?

Answer (score 2):

According to Gorm documentation :

> All Chain Methods will clone and create a new DB object (shares one
>   connection pool), GORM is safe for concurrent use by multiple
>   goroutines.

Gorm creates clones when it needs to automatically, there is no need to handle this manually. For more information check this page in the documentation: http://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html